# How to get a plain object from mobx object?

Tags: javascript, mobx, mobx-react

I defined a mobx map as below:

```
@observable editors = observable.map();
```

then I added object on the `editors` as below:

```
  editors.set(key, {
    alias: 'alias-1',
    message: 'hello',
  })
```

when I get the object from `editor` as below:

```
  let myEditor = editors.get(key)
```

the returned object `myEditor` has some builtin functions such as:

```
$mobx:ObservableObjectAdministration
get alias:function ()
set alias:function ()
get message:function ()
set message:function ()
```

I wander how I can get a plain javascript object from `editor`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [**toJS**](https://mobx.js.org/api.html#tojs).

**Example**

```
class MyStore {
  @observable editors = observable.map({});
}

const myStore = new MyStore();

myStore.editors.set('example', {
  alias: 'alias-1',
  message: 'hello'
});

console.log(toJS(myStore.editors));
```